# Tier-4 extension in the UK - Can I apply for premium service without passport?

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa

I had applied for extending my tier 4 visa but failed to submit my bank statements. I do have the required funds for the required period, but my mistake was in not submitting the documents the first time around.

I have a new CAS from the university now, and I wish to reapply. However my passport has not been returned to me. To overcome all waiting hassles, I wish to apply through the premium service. Can I book the premium service without the passport? Or should I try to get the passport from the Home Office before reapplying?